# When I run .\main.exe, it doesn't return 0

Tags: c++, configuration

I'm taking up a C++ programming course on Youtube by Daniel Gakwaya.
He was showing how to configure g++ to use C++20. When I run the main.exe, it didn't show the number 0 like in the tutorial.

It only showed this:

> PS E:\Work\Courses\Coding\C++\DanielGakwayaCourse\EnvironmentSetup\WindowsTemplateProject> .\main.exe
> PS E:\Work\Courses\Coding\C++\DanielGakwayaCourse\EnvironmentSetup\WindowsTemplateProject>

I tried reinstalling Visual Studio Code but it still showed the same result. I expected the number 0 appeared after I type .\main.exe in the terminal.

I wonder if it will affect anything because according to the video, there should be a 0 to show that the Visual Studio Code connected with g++ compiler.

Sorry if this question doesn't contain enough information. I'm a complete newbie in this.

Here's my main.cpp code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    auto result = (10 <=> 20) > 0;
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Here's the tasks.json code:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "Build with g++ 13.2.0",
            "command": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-std=c++20",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

[The tutorial code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyzB1.png)

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiZcE.png)

Comment: when you say "return" do you mean return or do you mean print on the screen? main does return 0 (unless you return something else)  and your code prints something to the console. Please include output as text in the question.

Comment: [Why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Your screenshot does not show any evidence of actually **compiling** main.exe. For all we know you are running a program that does not match the code.

Comment: Try double-clicking your .exe in the explorer, see if there's any error.

Comment: I tried to edit the post but I couldn't save it.

Here are the steps I took:
1. Type the code below in main.cpp
2. Go to Terminal -> Configure Tasks -> Choose C/C++: g++.exe build active file.
3. Edit the tasks.json file so that the result is as below.
4. Choose main.cpp. Go  to Terminal -> Run Task -> Choose Build with g++13.2.0.

Comment: The result in the Terminal shows:

 *  Executing task: Build with g++ 13.2.0 

Starting build...
C:\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -g -std=c++20 E:\Work\Courses\Coding\C++\DanielGakwayaCourse\EnvironmentSetup\WindowsTemplateProject\main.cpp -o E:\Work\Courses\Coding\C++\DanielGakwayaCourse\EnvironmentSetup\WindowsTemplateProject\main.exe

Build finished successfully.
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Comment: Then I typed .\main.exe in the terminal, it only showed the path to the project. It didn't show the number 0 like in the tutorial. 

I tried a couple of things:
1. reinstalling Visual Studio Code but it still showed the same result. 
2. opening the main.exe file and it only showed a black window and then disappeared.
3. putting the code to this <https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler> . When I ran it, this was the the result:
0



... Program finished with exit code 0.
Please ENTER to exit console.

Answer (score 0):

Your code did not compile successfully. I guess you are using a compiler that does not support C++ 20, which is essential for `strong_ordering` operator (<=>) or didn't use the c++20 flag.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/strong_ordering

you can test your code with an online compiler with C++ 20. for example:

https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler (make sure you select the c++ 20.)

Comment: I the code to this <onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler> . When I ran it, this was the the result: 0 ... Program finished with exit code 0. Please ENTER to exit console.

Comment: @Gin - That is a different 0. "Exit code 0" comes from the `return 0;` that the compiler adds at the end of `main` to report success, not from `cout`.

Comment: Thank you @BoP and SHR. How can I know which version of C++ the compiler supports?

Comment: @Gin - You don't ask, you *tell* the compiler what version you want, like `-std=c++20` in the json file.